# How to delete files after using grep function

Tags: linux, bash

I have the command below:

```
grep -rnw '/root/serviceDown/' -e "The service 'httpd' on server is currently down"
```

and the result is as follows:

```
/root/serviceDown/2946/000.conf:5:subject=The service 'httpd' on server is currently down
/root/serviceDown/2955/000.conf:5:subject=The service 'httpd' on server is currently down
```

How to write a script which deletes those files after the `grep` command and then restarts the server?

Comment: What commands did you try yourself for deleting or restarting the server back?

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
grep -lr "The service 'httpd' on server is currently down" /root/serviceDown/ 2>/dev/null | xargs rm
```

The `-n` and `-w` flags do not really make sense for your purpose, the additional information they produce is only in the way here. The `-e` flag is also not required as far as I can tell, you do not need an extended pattern interpretation for the string you use. The `-l` flag reduces the output to the name of matching files. You filter out the error output using `2>/dev/null` and finally pipe the resulting list of files into the `xargs`utility which uses a simple `rm` command to delete the files.

Restarting the server process afterwards can be done by whatever command you usually use for that, just execute it *after* the above command, either manually or separated by a simple `;` in one go.

Obviously you need sufficient system permission to be able to perform both commands...

---

For more advanced processing of the result as you ask in your comment below I suggest you implement a simple script. This offers much more flexibility, is easier to read and maintain and also allows execution as a single command.

This might be a starting point for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

# fetch list of matching files
list=`grep -lr "The service 'httpd' on server is currently down" /root/serviceDown/ 2>/dev/null`
if [[ -z "$list" ]]; then
  echo "No files matched, nothing to be done...";
  exit
fi

# delete files one by one
for match in $list
do
    echo "Removing matched file $match..."
    echo `rm $match`
done
# restart server process
echo "Restarting server process..."
`service httpd restart`
# that's is, basically
echo "...done."
```

Save that script into some folder inside your `PATH` environment variable (e.g.`/root/bin/restartFailedHttpdServer`), make it executable (`chmod u+x /root/bin/restartFailedHttpdServer`) and finally execute it (`restartFailedHttpdServer`).

Comment: How to add IF to xargs if it's no null then restart server ?

Comment: @aviaPL I added an approach for that additional requirement to the answer.